# Gradle Build Failed [UNITY 2019]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am trying to build my first project to Android and during build I am getting the following error.

I have been looking a lot at previous question but the fixes dont work or are not available in 2019 unity.

[IMAGE FULL RES](https://i.gyazo.com/a1cde97750f6ab354d2e876d633ce4c0.png)
[image]

Gradle.Build file

```
    // GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            // If you are changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, make sure it is compatible with the Gradle version preinstalled with Unity
            // See which Gradle version is preinstalled with Unity here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html
            // See official Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility table here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
            // To specify a custom Gradle version in Unity, go do "Preferences > External Tools", uncheck "Gradle Installed with Unity (recommended)" and specify a path to a custom Gradle version
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        }
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

Comment: Could you add the Gradle build file to the question? And if possible, run the same command with the `--stacktrace` file and post that as well.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what do you mean add the Gradle build file how can I find that. Im going to continue looking online searching stacktrace now thank you

Comment: On disk, your project has a `build.gradle` file. And the `--stacktrace` is a flag, not a file. My mistake. The idea would be to execute the build command with that flag added so you get more information as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry found this now and added to main post. And okay looking into it now thank you

Comment: I'm still unsure how to change the version of gradle I am using can anyone point me to a link showing how to do this as I cannot find anything. I will keep looking and post if I do